# Model Placement

Tags: python, django

It is necessary to place posts on the site so that they can be created and edited, but in the site design the posts are separated by sliders and other elements, how is it possible to implement this in such a way that the other layout elements are, so to speak, ignored?

I tried to solve this problem by creating additional models, that is, the posts before the separating elements (sliders in this case) should be taken in one class, and the subsequent ones in another and further edited in such a way. Of course this is a crutch, but I don’t know how to configure it, because together these models are not displayed for me, that is, either one or the other. I also created a separate class for the Main Post, because it has a different design and, as a matter of fact, always hangs in the top, but of course it’s ideal to implement such that the model has such an attribute that you can indicate to a specific post that it is the main and most located at the beginning of the site.

Here is my code (let's say that we added Posts_one, Posts_two, if we talk about the case of using a crutch, which I also failed):

**models.py**:

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Toppost(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        caption = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='краткое описание поста')
        text = models.TextField()
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

        def publish(self):
            self.published_date = timezone.now()
            self.save()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        caption = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='краткое описание поста')
        text = models.TextField()
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

        def publish(self):
            self.published_date = timezone.now()
            self.save()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post, Toppost

def posts_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/posts_list.html', {'posts': posts})

    topposts = Toppost.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/posts_list.html', {'topposts': topposts})
```

I also attach a screenshot with a diagram of how it should look.  Ideally, of course, it’s interesting to know how this can be implemented so that all this is one Post model and does not destroy the layout of the site and that you can select any post as Main_Post.

[image]

Comment: you have two return statements in the posts_list remove one and add the context of the other to it, then the context should be `{'topposts':topposts, 'posts':posts}` .  The question about the models i would suggest having only one model and adding a `is_toppost` BoleanField

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply add an attribute for a post to define whether it's a top post or not.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ... all the other stuff ...
    is_top_post = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # ... all the other stuff ...

# ...

def posts_list(request):
    all_posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by("published_date")
    non_top_posts = []
    top_posts = []
    for post in all_posts:
        (top_posts if post.is_top_post else non_top_posts).append(post)

    return render(request, "blog/posts_list.html", {"posts": non_top_posts, "top_posts": top_posts})
```

You can also ensure that there is exactly one top post by adding a save override like

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ... all the other stuff ...
    is_top_post = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # ... all the other stuff ...

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if self.is_top_post:
            # Un-top every other post
            Post.objects.exclude(id=self.id).update(is_top_post=False)
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution!  It works perfectly.
Tell me, if you can still have this:
   You see, if you look at the site’s layout, then there are 2 posts in front of the slider, and after slider 4, let's say that there is another slider and after it there are 4 more posts.  How do you need to write logic in order to implement this?

Comment: You could use the slice filter (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) within your template when you're looping over posts. `{% for post in non_top_posts |slice:":4" %}...before slider...{% endfor %}... slider ...{% for post in non_top_posts |slice:"4:" %}...after slider...{% endfor %}`

Comment: Yes, of course, I tried to use slices before, but the fact is that posts are simply copied, not divided into parts.

Comment: Thank you all, I solved this problem as follows: `{% for post in posts|slice:":2" %}... post code ...{% endfor %}... slider ...{% for post in posts|slice:"2:6" %}... post code ...{% endfor %}... slider ...{% for post in posts|slice:"6:11" %}... post code ...{% endfor %}`